# Not getting data from an API using retrofit

Tags: php, android, api, retrofit2

I have implemented a simple API in PHP and tested it using postman and it worked fine. But when I am using retrofit to get the data it doesn't work it only executes the onFailure() method on the en-queued request.

Retrofit interface

```
public interface UserAPI {

@POST("createUser.php")
Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
}
```

Retrofit Request

```
  Call<User> call = userAPI.createUser(user);

  call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {

      startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

    }

    @Override
     public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
       Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,t.getCause(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    });
```

User class

```
public class User {
 public int userId;
 public String username;
 public String realName;
 public String phoneNumber;
 public String email;
 public String password;
}
```

createUser.php implementation

```
require_once('./serviceDB.php');
require_once('./User.php');

header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");


if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

  $username = $data['user']['username'];
  $mobile = $data['user']['mobile'];
  $email = $data['user']['email'];
  $password = $data['user']['password'];

  $user = new User();

  $user->setUsername($username);
  $user->setEmail($email);
  $user->setMobile($mobile);
  $user->setPassword($password);
  serviceDB::createUser($user)
```

and the createUser method in the API

```
public static function createUser($user){
$query = 'Insert Into Users (Username, Email,Mobile, Password) VALUES (:username, :email, :mobile,:password)';
    $params = array(':username' => $user->username , ':email' => $user->email, ':mobile' => $user->mobile,':password' => $user->password);
$id = ServiceDB::Query($query, $params);
return $id;
```

}

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting?

Comment: what I meant is that only code on onFailure  method is executed and I am not getting any data

Comment: debug it you will get an error response.

Comment: the error I got on the onFailure method is malformed json exception